# Is the following proof by induction correct?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, induction

If we take m+1=1+m, 0+m=m+0=m and m+(n+1)=(m+n)+1 as axioms for any integer m and n, is this the correct proof by induction of the commutativity of x+y?

Suppose x+k = k+x for y = k

for y=k+1:

x+(k+1)

=(x+k)+1

=(k+x)+1

=1+(k+x)=(1+k)+x

=(k+1)+x

Hence, by induction, we have proved the commutativity of addition.

Comment: You should include in the statement "Suppose $x+k = k+x$ for $y=k$ *and for all $x \in \mathbb N$*".  And you should explicitly state a base case "For all $x \in \mathbb N$, $x+1 = 1+x$ via axiom".  But yes, your proof is sound. (Actually *is* if fair to take $1+m=m+1$?  If you are told you can, then you can, but is that a fair axiom?)

Comment: Hmm.... don't usually upvote *solely* to counter a downvote but... sheesh.... what was the point of that down-vote? The question was clearly written and showed work and had legimate concern.  (Upvoted to cancel)

Comment: @fleablood I agree this question is fairly well written (at least compared to many I've seen on this site), so I also don't believe it should have been downvoted.  Since I didn't downvote myself, I obviously can't say what the reason for it was. Nonetheless, I've fairly often seen downvotes on quite reasonable questions where it seems the main issue is just that the OP didn't use MathJax, so I suspect that may be a reason in a fair number of those cases, and it may also be a factor here as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid.  But it should explicitly state that that to prove $x+y=y+x$ for all $y$ and for all $x$, that you induction statement is going to be $P(y): x+y =y +x$ **for all $x$** and for that *specific* $n$.

And you should include a Base case:

Base case: $P(1):  y = 1$  Claim:  $x+1 = 1+x$ **for all $x$**.  Pf: We were given that and can take it for granted.

Then you proof is *perfect*  (good job!)

Induction step: Suppose $x +k = k + x$ for $y=k$ and **for all $x$** then

$x+ (k+1)=$
$(x+k)+1=$
$(k+x) + 1 =$
$1+(k+x) = $
$(1+k)+x=$
$(k+1)+x$.